# Reflection across a line

Tags: geometry, linear-transformations, reflection

Let $g$ be a line with equation $g:ax+by+c=0$ in Hesse normal form. I want to show that the reflection across $g$ is described by \begin{equation*}\binom{x}{y}\mapsto \binom{x}{y}-2(ax+by+c)\binom{a}{b}\end{equation*}

At the reflection across $g$ it holds the following for the image $P'$ of each point $P$:

- $P'$ lies on the perpendicular to $g$ through $P$.
- $g$ bisects $PP'$.

So to show the desired result, do we have to find the perpendicular line to $g$ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This reflection is an affine map, so we can represent it as linear map if we embed plane in $\mathbb R^3$ with $(x,y)\mapsto (x,y,1)$.

I will use the same idea as Robert Z, $P'$ is reflection of $P$ along the line $ax + by + c=0$ if two conditions are met:

> **(1)** $\ \displaystyle\frac{P+P'}2$ lies on the line $ax + by + c = 0$

We can describe this with linear equation $$\left\langle\frac{P+P'}2,(a,b,c) \right\rangle  = 0.$$

> **(2)** $\ P-P'$ is perpendicular to the line $ax + by + c = 0$

Direction vector of the line is given by $(-b,a,0)$, so $P'-P$ must be orthogonal to it, i.e. $$\left\langle P'-P,(-b,a,0)\right\rangle = 0.$$

If we write $P = (x,y,1),\ P'=(x',y',1)$, conditions (1) and (2) can be written as

\begin{align}
ax'+by'&= -ax - by - 2c\\
-bx'+ay' &= -bx+ay
\end{align}

or in matrix form
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
a & b & 0\\
-b & a & 0\\
0 & 0 & 1\\
\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}
x'\\
y'\\
1\\
\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}
-a & -b & -2c\\
-b & a & 0\\
0 & 0 & 1\\
\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}
x\\
y\\
1\\
\end{pmatrix}.$$

Invert the matrix on the left hand side to get

\begin{align}
\begin{pmatrix}
x'\\
y'\\
1\\
\end{pmatrix} &= \frac 1{a^2+b^2}\begin{pmatrix}
a & -b & 0\\
b & a & 0\\
0 & 0 & a^2+b^2\\
\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}
-a & -b & -2c\\
-b & a & 0\\
0 & 0 & 1\\
\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}
x\\
y\\
1\\
\end{pmatrix}\\
&= \frac {-1}{a^2+b^2}\begin{pmatrix}
a^2-b^2 & 2ab & 2ac\\
2ab & b^2-a^2 & 2bc\\
0 & 0 & -(a^2+b^2)\\
\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}
x\\
y\\
1\\
\end{pmatrix}
\end{align}

or if you want to get back to $\mathbb R^2$, we get affine map

$$\begin{pmatrix} x\\ y\end{pmatrix} \mapsto \frac {-1}{a^2+b^2}\begin{pmatrix}
a^2-b^2 & 2ab \\
2ab & b^2-a^2 
\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}
x\\
y
\end{pmatrix}-\frac {1}{a^2+b^2}\begin{pmatrix} 2ac\\ 2bc\end{pmatrix}.$$

Comment: Ah ok!! Is your last relation equivalent to the one of my initial post?

Comment: @Mary Star, I didn't write it down, but it looks like it. Just set $a^2+b^2 = 1$. For example, in my expression you get $-(a^2-b^2)x - 2ab y - 2ac = (1-2a^2)x - 2ab y -2ac$ in the first coordinate.

Comment: Ah ok! I checked that! I have also an other question. Why is this reflection is an affine map? How do we know that?

Comment: Well, it is [Mazur-Ulam theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mazur%E2%80%93Ulam_theorem) that any bijective isometry is an affine map, but you don't even need it here. That this reflection map is affine is a consequence of the calculations we did here. I added that first line just to point out my line of thought - I knew beforehand that this approach would work. @Mary Star

Comment: Ok!! thank you very much for your answer!! :-)

Answer (score 2):

For the first question it suffices to verify that $P-P'$ is orthogonal to $g$ that is $P-P'$ is parallel to $\binom{a}{b}$ which is true because
$$P-P'=2(ax+by+c)\binom{a}{b} \parallel \binom{a}{b}.$$

As regards the second question, we have that the midpoint of $PP'$ is
$$Q:=\frac{P+P'}{2}=\frac{1}{2}\left(\binom{x}{y}+\binom{x}{y}-2(ax+by+c)\binom{a}{b}\right)=\binom{x}{y}-(ax+by+c)\binom{a}{b}.$$
Now we verify that $g$ bisects $PP′$, that is $Q$ belongs to the line $g$:
$$\binom{a}{b}^t\cdot Q+c=ax+by-(ax+by+c)(a^2+b^2)+c=0$$
which holds because $a^2+b^2=1$.

P.S. The formula for reflection accross the line $ax+by+c$ with $a^2+b^2=1$
$$\binom{x}{y}\mapsto \binom{x}{y}-2(ax+by+c)\binom{a}{b}$$
can be "guessed" in this way:  $\binom{a}{b}$ is a unit vector orthogonal to the line, $ax+by+c$ is the signed distance of $(x,y)$ from the line (the sign depends on the orientation of $\binom{a}{b}$. Then to obtain the reflected point of $P$, we take $P$ and we subtract two times the component of $P$ along $\binom{a}{b}$.

Comment: @Mary Star Any further doubt?

Comment: Can we not derive the formula \begin{equation*}\binom{x}{y}\mapsto \binom{x}{y}-2(ax+by+c)\binom{a}{b}\end{equation*} ? Do we just have to prove that the properties of a reflection across a line hold, that it is indeed the reflection?

Comment: @MaryStar Yes, we guess the formula and then we verify the two properties which characterize rfelections.

Comment: Could you explain to me why we take $P$ and we subtract two times the component of $P$ along $\binom{a}{b}$ ? Is it because we substract once to have the distance from the point to the line $g$ and once to have the distance from the line to the reflected point?

Comment: @MaryStar Yes, you are correct!! Take also a look at the picture here: http://en.citizendium.org/wiki/Reflection_(geometry) Is it clear?

Comment: Ok!! Thank you so much!! :-)

Comment: @Mary Star You are welcome!

Answer (score 1):

We have the following line

$$\mathcal L := \{ \mathrm x \in \mathbb R^2 \mid \mathrm a^\top \mathrm x = b \}$$

in [Hessian normal form](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/HessianNormalForm.html), i.e., $\| \mathrm a \|_2 = 1$. The point in $\mathcal L$ closest to the origin is the least-norm solution

$$\mathrm x_{\text{LN}} := \mathrm a \left( \mathrm a^\top \mathrm a \right)^{-1} b = b \, \mathrm a$$

We introduce $\rm y:= x - x_{\text{LN}}$ to translate the line. We then have a line $\mathcal L'$ passing through the origin, a $1$-dimensional linear subspace, defined by $\mathrm a^\top \mathrm y = 0$. Note that

- the projection matrix that projects onto the orthogonal complement of $\mathcal L'$ is $\rm P := a a^\top$.
- the projection matrix that projects onto $\mathcal L'$ itself is $\rm I_2 - P = I_2 - a a^\top$.

We can write a vector $\rm y$ in terms of two components, one *orthogonal* to $\mathcal L'$ and the other *parallel* to $\mathcal L'$, i.e., $\rm y = P y + (I_2 - P) y$. Thus, the desired **reflection** is given by the following *linear* function

$$\rm y \mapsto -P y + (I_2 - P) y = (I_2 - 2 P) y$$

or, in terms of $\rm x$, by the *affine* function $\mathrm x \mapsto f (\mathrm x)$, where

$$\begin{array}{rl} f (\rm x) &:= \rm \mathrm x_{\text{LN}} + (I_2 - 2 P) (x - x_{\text{LN}})\\ &\,= \rm 2 P x_{\text{LN}} + (I_2 - 2 P) x\\ &\,= 2 b \, \mathrm a + \left( \mathrm I_2 - 2 \mathrm a \mathrm a^\top \right) \mathrm x\\ &\,= \mathrm x - 2 \mathrm a \left( \mathrm a^\top \mathrm x - b \right)\\ &\,= \color{blue}{\mathrm x - 2 \left( \mathrm a^\top \mathrm x - b \right) \mathrm a}\end{array}$$